# Not properly Grouping items in a collection with LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, .net-3.5

I've got a method that tries to Add n files to a repository, using SharpSVN. Any number of these files can throw an error, which I catch, and then move on to the next file and try to add that, and so on. I want to alert the user X times, where X is the number of different reasons. So if I added 5 files and 3 failed for one reason and 2 failed for a different reason, I want to present 2 errors. If they all fail for the same reason, 1 error. Five different reasons? Present 5 errors.

I made a class, `FileException`, that has two properties (`Exception` Ex, `string` FileName) and tried to implement a collection so I could group it on the Exception.

```
    public void AddFiles(List<string> files)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var args = new SvnAddArgs {Depth = SvnDepth.Children};
        var exes = new Collection<FileException>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                //only here for testing purposes described below
                if (file.Contains("png"))
                    throw new AccessViolationException();

                SVNClient.Add(file, args);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exes.Add(new FileException(ex, file));
            }
        }

        if (exes.Count > 1)
        {
            exes.GroupBy(s => s.Ex.GetType());
            Unique<Log>.Instance.AddExceptions(exes);
        }
        else if (exes.Count == 1)
            Unique<Log>.Instance.AddException(exes[0].Ex);
    }

    public void AddExceptions(Collection<FileException> e)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var ex = e[0].Ex;

        for(var i=0; i < e.Count;i++)
        {
            Logs.Add(new LogMessage(e[i].Ex));
            sb.AppendLine(e[i].FileName);
            WriteLogFile(new LogMessage(e[i].FileName, e[i].Ex));

            if (ex.GetType() == e[i].Ex.GetType()) 
                continue;

            ShowLogError(new LogMessage(sb.ToString(), ex));
            sb.Length = 0;
            ex = e[i].Ex;
        }

//Call ShowLogError if only 1 type of Exception in all of e
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString())) 
            ShowLogError(new LogMessage(sb.ToString(), ex));
    }

    public void ShowLogError(ILogMessage log)
    {
        //Extra formatting left out as its irrelevant to code sample
        XtraMessageBox.Show(log.message, log.title);
    }
```

So, what `AddException` is trying to do is store the first exception in `ex` in a sort of flag, and then iterate over its parameter and message the user when the current item is different than the flag item.

Test Case:

- Add 3 files (fileA.cs, fileB.png, fileC.cs)

Expected Results:

- ShowLogError() shows me fileA and fileC, since these threw the same error
- ShowLogError() shows me fileB, which threw the hard-coded exception since it contains "png"

Actual Results:

- ShowLogError() shows fileA and B, which threw 2 different exceptions
- ShowLogError() shows fileC, which threw the same as fileA.

So I think there's a problem with how I'm using `GroupBy()` in the AddFiles method, but I'm totally clueless here. Oh, also, I get this note from Resharper on my `GroupBy()` statement: `Return value of pure method is not used` but I'm not really sure what is meant by "pure method".

Edit: I just tried using OrderBy instead of GroupBy, but I get the same results for the aforementioned test case.

Edit 2: Using my OrderBy instead of GroupBy, here is a screenshot from my Immediate Window:
![enter image description here][1]

Added highlighting just to make it easier to differentiate the three rows.

Should items 0 and 2 be together since their `Ex` is of the same type?

**Edit** Adding a screenshot of Gert Arnold's answer to show that it does not compile. I proposed an edit that *does* compile and it was removed. I appreciate his help, of course, but it wasn't 100% working.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've got your `exes` collection, basically all you have to do is:

```
var result = fileExceptions.GroupBy(e => e.Ex.GetType().Name)
    .Select(g => new 
        { 
          g.Key, Files = string.Join("\r\n", g.Select(x => x.FileName).ToArray())
        });
```

Comment: Absolutely wonderful, this is exactly what I wanted. I made a quick edit as it wasn't 100% compiling right, but it was very close. Then I was just able to loop foreach r in result and call ShowLogError with r.Key and r.Files. Thank you.

Comment: @danielhanly please see the edit on my original post. Gert's answer, while very helpful, is not 100% correct. The edit I submitted to his post, that you rolled back, works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are not capturing the results of of your "GroupBy" or "OrderBy" clauses.

What about this:

```
        List<Type> types = exes.Select(x => x.GetType()).Distinct().ToList();
```

This gives you the unique types of FileExceptions that were added to the collection

Comment: `types` has 1 item, which is a `FileException`, since all x is is a collection of `FileException`s. Using x.Ex.GetType instead gives me 2 items, the two different exceptions my three files threw. I might be able to work with this, I think.

Comment: Alright, I was able to modify my AddExceptions method to utilize this line you suggested, and I was able to achieve my desired result by iterating over this collection, and the FileException collection and use a StringBuilder whenever the two exception types match up.